# Document Query Selector shows an element but when I use the same selector with puppeter doesn't work

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

guys so I do want to click a button, here is my code and the error that I get:

```
await page.goto("http://website.com", {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});

await page.click("[type=submit]")

// ERROR
Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement
```

I have even tried to wait for selector, still the same results, tried to get it with Xpath, the same resut

However, when I open the console in the same tab, even on the webdriver itself, using:

```
document.querySelector("[type=submit]")
// It returns this:
<button class="AnimatedForm__submitButton m-full-width" data-step="email" type="submit">
```

So basically the button is there but my puppeter can't find it. I can't see it to be inside an iframe. What else can it be ?

I have tried this as well:

```
await page.evaluate(selector=>{
return document.querySelector(['[type=submit]']).click();})
// ERROR
TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
```

Comment: Don't you have multiple submits on page? I'd try "[type='submit']" or "button[type='submit']" .

Comment: @digitalniweb it's only one submit. I will try as well like that, however, the rest of buttons on that website are working with this, only this one isn't which is weird

Comment: Other thing what comes to my mind is if you ended the tag properly with </button>

Comment: @digitalniweb hmm, I don't get your answer. Do you mean about modifying, my selector?

Comment: Button is a paired tag -> <button ...>...</button> But I guess that won't be a problem anyway.

Comment: button[type=submit] does the same issue. It's not about the selector, actually, I have to see, the page returns 2 iframes that have same url so I guess the button is in the second or something

Comment: am I getting correctly this: "the page returns 2 iframes that have same url so I guess the button is in the second or something", you mean the button might be in an iframe (your original question suggested the opposite)? if that is the case you will need to step inside the iframe to click it with puppeteer. `document` has a different scope in case of the `page` or the `frame`.

Comment: @theDavidBarton page.frames,yeah, returns 2 iframes which are not showing when inspecting the page.
I've tried reaching the frame but with no succes seems so, really weird that the browser console cand find it

Comment: I think that will be the cause of your issue. `document.querySelector(selector)` owns a different DOM-scope when you are running it within `page.xyz...` or `frame.xyz...` (`xyz... == evaluate || click` etc.) you will need to evaluate the iframe which contains the required button.

Comment: @theDavidBarton not sure what you're talking about bcs it's my first project with Puppeeter but i will search for it. Thank you!

Comment: no worries, I will explain it in an answer soon. hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a button inside an iframe:

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe name="myFrame" src="frame.html"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

**frame.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = 'red'
      }
    </script>
    <button class="AnimatedForm__submitButton m-full-width" data-step="email" type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">
      Michelle Branch - Spirit Room
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you run `document.querySelector('[type=submit]')` in the browser it will return the button correctly.

[image: elem in iframe]

But why won't it work in puppeteer then?

The page means the `index.html`'s DOM. Puppeteer can reach only elements within its normal DOM.

```js
const page = await browser.newPage()
```

But not the DOM within the `iframe`. It will be the scope of `frame.html`'s DOM, we can get it with `page.frames()` like this (e.g. by its `name` attribute):

```js
const frame = page.frames().find((frame) => frame.name() === 'myFrame')
```

Then we can communicate with the inner button as well. E.g.:

**script.js**

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

;(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('.../index.html')

  // await page.click('[type=submit]') // it doesn't find the element ❌

  const frame = page.frames().find((frame) => frame.name() === 'myFrame')
  await frame.click('[type=submit]') // it finds the element ✅

  // await browser.close()
})()
```

Comment: Yeah but actually I can't see the iframes when inspecting only when I console log the page frames

Comment: strange. is your webpage a public one you could share with us?